# Jquery ui dialog is opening multiple dialogs instead of one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery UI dialog to display some information coming up from an asp.net mvc view list.

so basically you go to the list, you click an icon and you get some info for the specific record as a pop up

If there is only one dialog in the page , there is no problem , the dialog will open fine but if i want to have more than one dialog then when i click any of them all will open.

Can you please help me with what am i doing wrong ?

```
 <td>                    
                <a class="clicker" dialogid="@item.Event.EventId" href="#"> Catering Details </a>
                <div class="dialog @item.Event.EventId" title=""> 
                     <p>@{Html.RenderAction("ViewEvent", "Home", new { EventId = item.Event.EventId });}</p>
                     </div>


                  @if (item.Event.SpecialRequirements != null)
             {
                  <img class="clicker2" dialog2id="@item.Event.EventId" style="margin-left:3px;display:inline;margin-bottom:-3px;cursor: pointer;" title="Special Requirements" src="~/Images/email-alert-icon.png"  /> 
                     <div class="dialog @item.Event.EventId" title="Special Requirements"> 
                     <p>@item.Event.SpecialRequirements</p>
                     </div>
             }  

        </td>

<script>
    $m = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script>

    $m(function ()
    {

        $m('.dialog').dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          show: { effect: "blind", duration: 1000 },
          hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 1000 },
          width:'800px',
          buttons: {
              Close: function () {
                  $m(this).dialog("close");
              }
          }
        });

      $m(".clicker").on("click", function () {
          $m("." + $(this).attr('dialogid')).dialog("open");
      });     

      $m(".clicker2").on("click", function () {
          $m("." + $(this).attr('dialog2id')).dialog("open");
      });

  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your HTML structure, I think you can avoid using additional classes or IDs here (in case you're using them just for that, of course).

Consider the following HTML:

```
<td>                    
    <a class="clicker" href="#">Catering Details</a>
    <div class="dialog" title=""> 
        // Your info
    </div>

    @if (item.Event.SpecialRequirements != null)
    {
        <img class="clicker" src="~/Images/email-alert-icon.png"  /> 
        <div class="dialog" title="Special Requirements"> 
            // Your info
        </div>
    }  

</td>
```

In your JS, you can open just the next dialog:

```
$(".clicker").on("click", function () {
    $(this).next('.dialog').dialog("open");
});
```

**EDIT:**

In case you wanna use the ids, I think you can just change the class of the second dialog box:

```
<td>                    
    <a class="clicker" dialogid="@item.Event.EventId" href="#">Catering Details</a>
    <div class="dialog @item.Event.EventId" title=""> 
        // Your info
    </div>

    @if (item.Event.SpecialRequirements != null)
    {
        <img class="clicker2" dialogid="@item.Event.EventId" src="lalala"  /> 
        <div class="dialog2 @item.Event.EventId" title="Special Requirements"> 
            // Your info
        </div>
    }  

</td>
```

And the JS would be:

```
$m('.dialog, .dialog2').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: { effect: "blind", duration: 1000 },
    hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 1000 },
    width:'800px',
    buttons: {
        Close: function () {
            $m(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$m(".clicker").on("click", function () {
    $m(".dialog." + $(this).attr('dialogid')).dialog("open");
});     

$m(".clicker2").on("click", function () {
    $m(".dialog2." + $(this).attr('dialogid')).dialog("open");
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: it wont really help because its a list within a foreach loop and basically it needs to pick up the unique id of each record and display the information for that record

Comment: But the information is the next tag after the record, right? If it is, this method will solve your problem, as it's picking the information next to the record.

Comment: nop , its identifying the record id from here : dialogid="@item.Event.EventId"

Answer (score 0):

You have used $m('.dialog').Which will open all the dialogs as you have specified the class name.

You can give each dialog a unique id and replace the $m('.dialog') with $('#dialogId');

Comment: it wont really help because its a list within a foreach loop and basically it needs to pick up the unique id of each record and display the information for that record